# Preview corresponding image in gallery on hover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several images and when I hover over one of the many icons I only want to show the corresponding image as a sort of preview which is hidden in the CSS.

The HTML can not be changed unfortunately. Also i have to do this with JS/jQuery.

At the moment all images showing up on hover. Obviously that is stupid!

Hope that makes sense? Thanks so much for your help! Cheers!

Torsten

HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
.previewBox img {
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span class="cell name">
    <img class="downloadIcon" src="1s.jpg" alt="Download">
    <a class="download-a" href="#">Test1</a>
</span>
<span class="cell size">(1212 KB)</span>
<div class="previewBox">
    <img src='1.jpg'>
</div>

<span class="cell name">
    <img class="downloadIcon" src="2s.jpg" alt="Download">
    <a class="download-a" href="#">Test2</a>
</span>
<span class="cell size">(900 KB)</span>
<div class="previewBox">
    <img src='2.jpg'>
</div>

<span class="cell name">
    <img class="downloadIcon" src="3s.jpg" alt="Download">
    <a class="download-a" href="#">Test3</a>
</span>
<span class="cell size">(1500 KB)</span>
<div class="previewBox">
    <img src='3.jpg'>
</div>
</div>

<!-- hover preview js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="hover-preview.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$('.cell').hover(function() {
    $('.previewBox img').fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
});
```

Comment: So long as the class for all of your "previewBox" elements are the same, anytime you trigger your fade animation, those elements are going to show. You need to either give them specific class names or put them inside the hover element.

Comment: Thanks Himmel, that what I thought too but unfortunately I cannot change the html. However how would the script look like then? Cheers T

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    $('.cell').hover(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.previewBox').find('img').fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
    });

})
```

```css
.previewBox img {
        display:none;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- hover preview js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="hover-preview.js"></script>

    <div>
    <span class="cell name">
        <img class="downloadIcon" src="1s.jpg" alt="Download">
        <a class="download-a" href="#">Test1</a>
    </span>
    <span class="cell size">(1212 KB)</span>
    <div class="previewBox">
        <img src='1.jpg'>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="cell name">
        <img class="downloadIcon" src="2s.jpg" alt="Download">
        <a class="download-a" href="#">Test2</a>
    </span>
    <span class="cell size">(900 KB)</span>
    <div class="previewBox">
        <img src='2.jpg'>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="cell name">
        <img class="downloadIcon" src="3s.jpg" alt="Download">
        <a class="download-a" href="#">Test3</a>
    </span>
    <span class="cell size">(1500 KB)</span>
    <div class="previewBox">
        <img src='3.jpg'>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please note there is change in Html too, and added snippet dont have hover js cdn so just showing the preview div

Comment: oops sorry, you are right it does work indeed! Thanks a lot!